# How can you find the parent snapshot of a zfs clone?

Tags: filesystems, zfs

I made a clone of zfs filesystem that has a number of snapshots.  I also have several replicated copies of the filesystem.

How can I find which filesystem/snapshot a clone is attached to?

(Seems like something that should be in the docs/googlable but I haven't found anything)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a special property called `origin` which holds what you need. Let's assume we have a zpool `tank` and a filesystem `tank/f1` and we create a snapshot and a clone:

```
 zfs snapshot tank/f1@s1
 zfs clone tank/f1@s1 tank/f2
```

Let's check the origin of that clone:

```
zfs get origin tank/f2
```

Output:

```
NAME     PROPERTY  VALUE       SOURCE
tank/f2  origin    tank/f1@s1  -
```

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your zfs list output... but you can also look at the output of: `zpool history` to see the command sequences and actions (*manual and automated*) performed on the pool. That may help refresh your memory. Filter for `clone` commands if there's too much output.

```
[root@GreenLeaf ~]# zpool history
History for 'vol0':
2013-09-14.16:57:19 zpool create -o ashift=12 vol0 fioa
2013-09-14.16:57:26 zfs create vol0/ppro2
2013-09-14.16:57:32 zfs set recordsize=32K vol0/ppro2
2013-09-15.14:52:08 zfs create -s -V 750G vol0/pprovol
2013-09-15.14:55:23 zfs destroy vol0/pprovol
2013-09-15.14:58:06 zfs create -o volblocksize=64K -s -V 750G vol0/pprovol

History for 'vol1':
2012-12-31.16:13:01 zpool create -f vol1 /dev/sdb
2012-12-31.16:13:22 zfs create vol1/ppro
2012-12-31.16:13:47 zfs set atime=off vol1/ppro
2012-12-31.16:13:55 zfs set compress=on vol1/ppro
2012-12-31.16:15:05 zfs set mountpoint=/ppro vol1/ppro
2012-12-31.21:07:37 zfs create vol1/pproold
2012-12-31.21:08:17 zfs set compress=gzip-9 vol1/pproold
2012-12-31.21:08:53 zfs set mountpoint=/ppro/pproold vol1/pproold
2012-12-31.22:20:56 zfs create vol1/ppro1
2012-12-31.22:21:12 zfs set compress=gzip-9 vol1/ppro1
2012-12-31.22:21:32 zfs set mountpoint=/ppro/ppro1 vol1/ppro1
2013-01-01.11:15:07 zpool set autoexpand=on vol1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another simple method:

```
zfs list -o name,origin | egrep ".@."
```

and without rpool:

```
zfs list -o name,origin | egrep -v "^rpool" | egrep ".@."
```

Comment: ... and `zfs list -o name,origin | grep -v ' -$'` if you want to keep the headers )